# error when start up tomcat with log4j: log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have 2 issues with the log4j and maybe one causes the other.

1. when I tried to start up my tomcat I get this **error**:

> log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.rollingFile

2. I cannot insert the log line to DB.

log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, S, rollingFile, sql

log4j.appender.S =org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.S.layout =org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.appender.rollingFile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File =C:\\log.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.Append = true
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=2000KB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=19

log4j.appender.rollingFile.Threshold = ALL

log4j.appender.rollingFile.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c{1} [%p] %m%n


log4j.appender.sql=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.sql.URL=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://devsql/DBName
log4j.appender.sql.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.sql.user=user_name
log4j.appender.sql.password=password


log4j.appender.sql.sql=INSERT INTO Log (logTypeId,logServiceId,hostId,logDateTime,logTitle,logModule,logDesc,logLineNumber,logStackTrace,userId) VALUES('%p','Project','172.0.12.123',now(),'%c{1}','%c{2}',N'%m','%L','%throwable{200}','%X{userId}')

log4j.appender.sql.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

my class is:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class BasicApi {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BasicApi.class.getName());


public ResponseEntity<String> runApi(InputBo input) {

    LOG.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!trying1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    LOG.debug("!!!!!!!!!!!!!trying2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");        

}
```

}

the **error** is:

> log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.rollingFile
>   log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "rollingFile".

important thing: this code is under maven jar project that another project adds it as a dependency. 
can you please help me whats wrong in this code? Thanks

Comment: so add one for log4j.appender

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: where did you configure everything?

Comment: the properties file is log4j.properties file and the dependencies are in pom.xml